# Rearranging data from one table to another in spreadsheets using apps script

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need some help with making my code run faster. It currently works by going through all cells in a 201x151 table. If the value in a cell is not equal to zero, then it will return the row number, the column number, and the actual value, and put it in a different table.

Here is the code:

```
function rearranger() {
  
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2:C10000');
  
  var ratings = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('TopChampionsVSUser!A1:EU201');
  
  var iterationNumber = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('I1:I2').getValues();
  
  var tr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L1').getCell(1, 1).getValue();
  
  var r = iterationNumber[0];
  var c = iterationNumber[1];
  
  for(r; r < 3000; r++){
    
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('I1').getCell(1, 1).setValue(r);
    
    if(c >= 151){
      c = 2;
    }
    
    for(c; c < 152; c++){
      
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('I2').getCell(1, 1).setValue(c);
      
      var currentCellValue = ratings.getCell(r, c).getValue();
      
      if(currentCellValue != 0){
        
        range.getCell(tr, 1).setValue(r-1);
        range.getCell(tr, 2).setValue(ratings.getCell(1, c).getValue());
        range.getCell(tr, 3).setValue(currentCellValue);
        
        tr++;
        
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L1').getCell(1, 1).setValue(tr);
        
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Do you see something you think can be improved or made more efficient?